# Does EditText.getText() ever returns null?

Tags: android, android-edittext

All over the net I see examples like `edittext.getText().toString()`. I do not see any null check. In docs I do not see any statement that would say that this will never be null.

Still, what does the observations say; does this ever return null?

Comment: String s=edittext.getText().toString(); if(s!=null)return true;

Comment: My question is, will EditText.getText() ever return null? @tsp your code will result in NPE in that case.

Comment: Maybe the warning is really saying "the user might have typed the word, 'null'" into the edittext. teehee!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`getText()` will not return `null`. So there is no chance for NPE in following method. the `getText` will return empty string if there is no string, which is definitely not `null`

```
getText().toString();
```

However the edittext itself can be `null` if not initialized properly, Hence the following will trigger NPE

```
editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: As a bonus, you can't even `setText(null)`. If you try it will internally [convert](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Candroid.widget.TextView.BufferType%2Cboolean%2Cint%29) it to an empty string.

Comment: If you check the source code of `TextView` then you'll see that `getText()` will never return `null`.

Comment: EditText won't, but EditTextPreference will return null and cause NPE if not prevented.

Comment: A link to Google documentation that verifies this would be helpful.

Answer (score 32):

**UPDATE:**

It does appear as of Jan 18, 2018 this is [now possible](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/b102cc24354fb2e44964b60a794746df86be1eb7#diff-d65d9c796a5d459f49303c3e5ac20480).

**OLD ANSWER:**

No, `EditText.getText()` never returns `null`. One way to verify this is to check the Android source code for `EditText.getText()`:

[EditText.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java) shows:

```
public Editable getText() {
    return (Editable) super.getText();
}
```

Since `EditText extends TextView`, the call to `super.getText()` must be `TextView.getText()`. Now we move on to `TextView.getText()` to see what it returns:

[TextView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) shows:

```
public CharSequence getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

Now we need to know if `mText` could ever be null.

Digging deeper into the TextView.java source we see that `mText` is initialized as an empty string in the `TextView` constructor:

```
public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mText = "";
    …
}
```

Once we see that the `EditText` constructor calls the `TextView` constructor:

```
public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

we can safely conclude that `EditText.getText()` can never return `null`, because as soon as an `EditText` is constructed, `mText` is given a value of an empty string.

**However**, as StinePike pointed out, `EditText.getText()` can possibly cause an NPE if your EditText is `null` when it makes the call to `getText()`.

Answer (score 10):

With **Android P** SDK it is annotated as nullable in the `AppCompatEditText` class so it can return null.

And from [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatEditText?hl=en#getText()):

> Return the text that the view is displaying. If an editable text has not been set yet, this will return null.

```
@Override
@Nullable
public Editable getText() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
        return super.getText();
    }
    // A bug pre-P makes getText() crash if called before the first setText due to a cast, so
    // retrieve the editable text.
    return super.getEditableText();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so it will ever return `null`.

But if you want to check whether the returned text is empty or not might I suggest using `TextUtils.isEmpty()` method

**Edit:-**  The documentation doesn't states anything regarding the returned value. And from what I've seen in the source code is that when you initialize a EditText, the default text value is set to `""`. So it will never return `null`

Answer (score 1):

it will return null because when apps runs its empty and it returns null, use .getText.toString inside a button click listener, now when you click button it will get the text which you have entered on editText.

Answer (score 0):

it is just because your `edittext.getText().toString()` is called directly in `onCreate()`...
This is why it return the initial value of editText.
You just have to create a function out of `onCreate()` and call it in event listener.

```
onCreate (){
      ….............
     btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
                getValue ()
         }
     });

}

public void getValue () {
    String editTextValue= edittext.getText().toString();
    ......
}
```

Or you Can call it directly in you `onClickListenner` in `onCreate()`.
Like this:

```
onCreate (){
      ….............
     btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
                String editTextValue= edittext.getText().toString();
                ..... 
         }
     });

}
```

I Hope it will be helpful!

Answer (score -9):

try in this way

```
String edittext = edittext.getText().toString();
if(edittext.length==0){ Log.d("null","the valueis null")};
```

Comment: I'm not the person who downvoted it, but in your example `edittext` is not `null`, it is an empty string. If it was `null`, calling `edittext.length` would throw a NPE. Also `length()` is a method BTW.

Comment: Also you have used "edittext" as the name of both the String and the EditText variable and your answer did not address the question asked.