# Validation for empty edittext in android

Tags: android

**What i am doing:**:

- I have two `edittext` and i am trying to perform validation on them
- condition i am checking is if both are not having nothing entered pop
  a dialog box

**Code i am using for validation**::

```
private void chkUsrIpValidation() {
        if((edtTxtCity.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))&&(edtTxtDate.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))){
            DlgUniversalError.showCustomAlert(getActivity(), "Please enter the city name");
        }   
    }
```

**Error i am facing**::

```
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.findmybuffet.fragments.FrgMdSearch.chkUsrIpValidation(FrgMdSearch.java:126)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.findmybuffet.fragments.FrgMdSearch.access$0(FrgMdSearch.java:118)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.findmybuffet.fragments.FrgMdSearch$1.onClick(FrgMdSearch.java:110)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-07 23:01:38.431: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

How can i resolve this, Am i specifying `&&` condition wrong ?

Comment: use `EditText.getText().toString().matches("") ` to check if edittext is empty or not..

Comment: Point line 126 likely the view may be nuull

Comment: oops yes edittest may be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my EditTexts must be null.  Those are `edtTxtCity.getText()` and `edtTxtDate.getText()` are the only two points in the if-statement that can cause an NPE.

It may also be easier to use `TextUtils` to check in which you got `TextUtils.isEmpty(edtTxtCity.getText())`.  It'll return `true` whether the text is null or empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590472/does-edittext-gettext-ever-returns-null. `getText()` will not return null. it returns a empty string. But you are right on the textutils part

Comment: Then the edittext must be null.  Those are the only two fault points.

Comment: Yup TextUtils is a better way approach and ...also i had not created an instance of edtTxtDate ... that was also a mistake i made thus it was returning null

Answer (score 0):

```
if(null != edtTxtCity 
&& edtTxtCity.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not the following,

```
private void chkUsrIpValidation() 
{
    if((edtTxtCity.getText() != null || edtTxtDate.getText() != null)
    {
        if(!"".equals(edtTxtCity.getText().toString()) || !"".equals(edtTxtDate.getText().toString())
        {
            DlgUniversalError.showCustomAlert(getActivity(), "Please enter the city name");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Well I could merge them but it would be a mess.

Comment: no need to merge also using `TextUtils.isEmpty(str)` will return a boolean value which is enough`

Comment: also I think I did the inverse condition and it should NOT throw error inside, it should be the opposite. Gah.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590472/does-edittext-gettext-ever-returns-null. `geText()` does not return null