# Can I initialize a final string dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I had tried this but the value of string **uname** always remains null.

```
EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.ID.newusername);
final String uname=username.getText().toString();
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: And what's the result of username.getText()

Comment: you're sure there's sth in that `EditText`?

Comment: the value that i entered in the edit text field.

Comment: It is impossible for `uname` to end up as `null` in the code you posted. If `username` is `null`, you'll get a NullPointerException; otherwise you'll get some kind of string (maybe empty), but never `null`. Are you sure you are checking the right variable? (A local variable may be hiding a field.)

Comment: why you declare uname as final ?

Comment: [EditText can never return null](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19590658/3326331)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would declare it as follows:

```
final String uname;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newusername);
    uname = username.getText().toString();
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: would you be so kind to upvote my answer if it helped? thanks :)

Comment: it solved my problem.but i don't have enough reputation to vote up. :(

Comment: you need to find your area of expertise and answer some questions for your reputation to increase.

Comment: You can now upvote. Can you do it please? Serves to promote fellow developers' work :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put something in the `editText`, before attempting to read its value, else it will always be null. Also, it's `R.id`... lowercase.

From Java code:

```
username.setText("testestestest");
uname = username.getText().toString();
```

In XML code:

```
<EditText
android:text="Default username"/>
```

Alternatively, add a listener to it, and read the input inside the listener.

```
username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {                   
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     if(s!=null && s.length() > 0){
         //do stuff
     }                         
  }                  
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }                     
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                     
  }
});
```

Now it won't be null.