# Getting NullPointerException while trying to extract text from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on this `onClick()`-method. On the line with

```
String standardT = smsText.getText().toString().
```

This is the `setStandardSMS` method and `alertDialog` I'm having problems with.

```
public void setStandardSMS(){
AlertDialog.Builder standardSMSBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.standard_text, null)
standardSMSBuilder.setView(view);
final EditText smsText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.standard_sms);
standardSMSBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.saveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    CharSequence text = "Du maa fylle inn alle felt!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    String standardT = smsText.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(standardT)){
        Intent newIntent = getIntent();
        newIntent.putExtra("tag_text_txt", standardT);
        setResult(2, newIntent);
    } else {
        toast.show();
    }

}
});

smsDialog = standardSMSBuilder.create();
standardSMSBuilder.show();
}
```

standard_text.xml

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/standard_sms"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:lines="8"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
/>
```

All I really want is to save the text which the user writes in, into a database. But the code keeps breaking here.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: Updated with the whole setStandardSMS-method, and standard_text.xml.

Comment: premature call of `findViewById`? you have to call it **after** `setContentView`... (with assumption that you are using Activity)

Comment: Nope, its not premature. It's after the setContentView.

Comment: Just do `String standardT = smsText.getText()` for now. Does it throw a NullPointerException?

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja first EditView.getText do not return String second is seems like it can't returns null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590472/does-edittext-gettext-ever-returns-null

Comment: R.id.standard_sms exsists and it's not premature. *tips fedora FSM*

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja The database is expecting a String, so doing that will not work.

Comment: then question should be closed as offtopic, since: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` ... seems like you are using dialog ... and you didn't tell us where this EditView is located in activity's layout or dialog's layout ...

Comment: @Selvin I meant to test whether or not smsText was null.

Comment: Add more code, that might give us better picture of your problem.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 added the whole setStandardSMS-method and standard_text.xml file

Comment: @adamNature see my answer. Try using this code. Let me know if it works/doesn't work

Comment: @Selvin What do you mean? I am calling on the layoutfile standard_text with: `R.layout.standard_text` and using the correct name of the `EditText`, namely standard_sms

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
public void setStandardSMS(){
AlertDialog.Builder standardSMSBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.standard_text, null)
standardSMSBuilder.setView(view);
final EditText smsText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.standard_sms);
standardSMSBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.saveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        CharSequence text = "Du maa fylle inn alle felt!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        String standardT = smsText.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(standardT)){
            Intent newIntent = getIntent();
            newIntent.putExtra("tag_text_txt", standardT);
            setResult(2, newIntent);
        } else {
            toast.show();
        }

    }
});

smsDialog = standardSMSBuilder.create();
standardSMSBuilder.show();
}
```

Comment: Atleast now it wrote out the toast! Thanks. So obviously still not finding the input though.

Comment: Now when you are not getting NPE anymore, you can debug it to get the cause of not getting input value.

Answer (score 0):

`getText()` might return null. That means your call `toString()` possibly throws a `NullPointerException`. To avoid that you can instead use `String.valueOf()`.

Here's how you properly test if a string is empty (null or length=0):

```
String standardT = String.valueOf(smsText.getText());

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(standardT)) {
    Intent newIntent = getIntent();
    newIntent.putExtra("tag_text_txt", standardT);
    setResult(2, newIntent);
} else {
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: @Selvin ah my bad. It returns Editable which extends CharSequence. So the conversion is required but not necessarily with toString(). Lemme update on that.