# Cleanest way to create an object, passing parameters from ArrayList of EditText

Tags: java, android

I've created an ArrayList with my EditText inputs for Android. This is in main activity

First i check if any are empty

```
for(EditText i: inputs){
    if(i.getText().toString() == null){
        empty = true;
}
```

then

```
if (!empty){
    for(EditText i: inputs) {
        String input = i.getText().toString();

        Person gen = new Person(inputFirstName.getText().toString(),
inputLastName.getText().toString(), inputMaiden.getText().toString(),
 inputBirth.getText().toString(), inputBrand.getText().toString());

        }else{    createAlertDialog("Alert", "One or more inputs are empty"); }
```

I'm aware in its current state it won't work, and just create 5 instances of the Person object. That is the layout of the constructor, and I want to find out the cleanest way to construct the object.

The repetition of .getText().toString() is dirty. Surely there is a cleaner way to do this using the ArrayList properties

Comment: You could modify the person object to take the return value of getText() and call toString() there by causing a method called internally inside the Person class.

Comment: The `i.getText().toString()` check is not necessary. Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19590658/1552587

Comment: Assuming you initialized all of your EditTexts, they shouldn't return null. You should change your empty check to if(i.getText().toString().isEmpty()).

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s ah! Thanks

Comment: @mewc if(i.length() == 0) is another option.

Answer (score 2):

It may appear to be an advanced approach but you may find Android DataBinding useful.
http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html