# Does TextView.getText() ever returns null?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

Similar to the following question [Does EditText.getText() ever returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590472/does-edittext-gettext-ever-returns-null), but with `TextView` instead of `EditText`.

Will `TextView.getText()` return null if the `XML` definition for the view does not include `android:text` or if `android:text=""`?

Comment: It will never return `null`

Comment: No, Expect if you wrote null as a text then it will return "null"

Comment: Obviously the answer is the same as with EditText is derived from TextView. `public Editable getText() { return (Editable) super.getText(); }` **Moreover it is written in one of the answers. So this question is duplicate...**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does EditText.getText() ever returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590472/does-edittext-gettext-ever-returns-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO.** `textView.getText()` will never return `null`. By definition `getText()` is as follows .

```
public CharSequence getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

And you can see the instance variable `mText` initialized with `mText=""`  just inside the constructor of `TextView` . You can have a look at [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) of `TextView`.

```
public TextView(
    Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    mText = "";
    ......... 
}
```

So it will either return text and `""` if there is not text.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you be able to provide a source for that piece of code please?

Comment: You can start with android tutorial from developers.google.com

Comment: You can check source code in android studio . i have also attached a link above .